# consuming a web api and getting a referenceerror

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, http, post

When trying to post and get data from my web api, I am getting this exception in the browser:

> angular.js:13708 ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>       at new  (GbyG.js:23)
>       at Object.invoke (angular.js:4709)
>       at $controllerInit (angular.js:10234)
>       at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:9147)
>       at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:8510)
>       at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:9210)
>       at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:8510)
>       at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:8513)
>       at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:8513)
>       at publicLinkFn (angular.js:8390)

Here is my client (written in angular):

```
app.controller('GetSamplesByStatus',
function($scope, $http) {
    var serializedData = $.param({statustype:"Received"});

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: ("http://localhost:36059/api/Samples/GetSamplesByStatus"),
    data: serializedData,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }}).then(function(response) {
        //$scope.dataset = response;
        console.log(error);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: `$` in `$.param({statustype:"Received"})` is undefined. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: thank you for the comment. i'm just trying to POST that URL: http://localhost:36059/api/Samples/GetSamplesByStatus?statustype=Received and retrieve the results of the POST

Comment: $.param is usually used to create a url query string.

Comment: Are you sure you have included jquery? coz not sure if $.param is available in jqlite which is part of angular.

Comment: @Iceman is there a different way to do this? i have no included jquery, the code im show above is angular (but i guess it is not), sorry beginner with the front end here

Comment: $httpParamSerializerJQLike service in ng

Comment: sorry, do not understandf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the angular docs for $httpParamSerializerJQLike
 which does the same serialisation work like jQuery.param() [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike)

```
.controller(function($http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) {
  //...

  $http({
    url: myUrl,
    method: 'POST',
    data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(myData),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  });

});
```

So in your case something like this:

```
app.controller('GetSamplesByStatus',
    function($scope, $http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) {
        var myParams = {statustype:"Received"};
        $http({
          url: "http://localhost:36059/api/Samples/GetSamplesByStatus%0A",
          method: 'GET',
          params: myParams,
          paramSerializer: '$httpParamSerializerJQLike'
        }).then(function(response) {
            //$scope.dataset = response;
            console.log(response.data);
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    });
```

See working example here: http://jsbin.com/madetefeya/edit?js,console

Comment: thank you, how would i incorporate that into this code: http://i.imgur.com/hzX1r0j.png

Comment: angular.js:11881 OPTIONS http://localhost:36059/api/Samples/GetSamplesByStatus (anonymous function) @ angular.js:11881sendReq @ angular.js:11642serverRequest @ angular.js:11352processQueue @ angular.js:16170(anonymous function) @ angular.js:16186$eval @ angular.js:17444$digest @ angular.js:17257$apply @ angular.js:17552bootstrapApply @ angular.js:1754invoke @ angular.js:4709doBootstrap @ angular.js:1752bootstrap @ angular.js:1772angularInit @

Comment: angular.js:1657(anonymous function) @ angular.js:31468trigger @ angular.js:3198defaultHandlerWrapper @ angular.js:3488eventHandler @ angular.js:3476
tabs.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:36059/api/Samples/GetSamplesByStatus. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405
GbyG.js:28 Object {data: null, status: -1, config: Object, statusText: ""}

Comment: r u sure that url is working. like cud u chk it with postman or curl

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115953/discussion-between-iceman-and-l).